JWT Decoding don't decode "role" field
I try to make WebAPI using ASP.NET. I make JWT authorization. JWT generate metod look like:
public string GenerateToken(string username, string roleName, int lifeDurationMinutes)
{
    List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>()
    {
        new Claim(type: ClaimsIdentity.DefaultNameClaimType, username),
        new Claim(type: ClaimTypes.Role, roleName),
        new Claim(type: ClaimTypes.Expiration, DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(lifeDurationMinutes).ToString())
    };

    SecurityTokenDescriptor tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor()
    {
        Issuer = configuration["jwt:Issuer"],
        Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(claims),
        SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(
            new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(configuration["jwt:Key"]!)), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
    };

    SecurityTokenHandler tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

    SecurityToken token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);

    return tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
}

Access token don't throw any exceptions, but when i try to refresh with validate method (code below), JwtSecurityHandler.ValidateToken method don't decode role field (it's just missing, not even null). When i use JWT.IO it shows me correct decoding (with role field).
public ClaimsPrincipal? VerifyToken(string token)
{
    Console.WriteLine(token);

    JwtSecurityTokenHandler handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

    TokenValidationParameters validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = false,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidIssuer = configuration["jwt:Issuer"],
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(configuration["jwt:Key"]!))
    };

    SecurityToken verifiedToken;

    if (handler.CanReadToken(token))
    {
        try
        {
            ClaimsPrincipal claims = handler.ValidateToken(token, validationParameters, out verifiedToken);
            return claims;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            return null;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

I use SwaggerUI to try validation. Besides, i tried to make refresh action with my react app. Validation parameteres in validation method are same with services configuration. If i will try to modify generate method (set Claims field instead of Subject with my claims list) when i refresh it throws IDX10225: Lifetime validation failed. The token is missing an Expiration Time. So, what's wrong?

Is it a single role or a list of roles?

@koogel, it's a single role (string variable)

I see that you haven't added JWT authorization in your Program.cs why did you add it as a separate function?

@koogel, it's added in program.cs too. This validation parameters needs to validate refresh token. This parameters are same with parameters in program.cs. Error in validation is my problem.

Try setting ValidateAudience = true,
